# Arduino not recognised by windows after using a lot of the storage

Tags: windows

I made a script for my Arduino Pro Micro that was very large (Global variables were 98% of the intended storage). The Arduino was not recognised by Windows after loading the script and I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: reset it while it attempts to upload, to start the bootloader. try double reset if simple reset doesn't work

Comment: Not recognized means, it was not recognized at the corresponding COM port or don't you simply get any communication on the serial port while the sketch is (should be) running?

Comment: on Micro the MCU (32u4)  has native USB handled by your sketch (the part from Arduino core), so if the sketch doesn't run, the USB is not handled. the IDE can reset the MCU only if it listens on USB (with 1200 baud connection). if you activate the bootloader with reset, it will handle USB while it is active